# REGEX: Add a pattern to not match my pattern in certain scenarios

Tags: javascript, regex

I currently have this wonderful pattern that seems to really work well for me to match links/urls

```
/(\b(https?|ftp|file):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])/gi
```

I'm using this pattern to find links and insert BBCODE around my links, so  if my example text is `http://www.google.com`, my output will be `[url]http://www.google.com[/url]`

The hard part is that if my input text already has BBCODE in it, for example `[url]http://www.google.com[/url]` then my output gets 2x the BBCODE placed around it.  `[url][url]http://www.google.com[/url][/url]`

Im hoping to somehow not match for links that already have [url] encasing the link.

**SUMMARY**

Current pattern:  `/(\b(https?|ftp|file):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])/gi`

Current output:

```
http://www.google.com ==> [url]http://www.google.com[/url]   
[url]http://www.google.com[/url] ==> [url][url]http://www.google.com[/url][/url]
[url="http://www.google.com"]http://www.google.com[/url] ==> [url][url="http://www.google.com"]http://www.google.com[/url][/url]
```

Desired output:

```
http://www.google.com ==> [url]http://www.google.com[/url]   
NO MATCHING [url]http://www.google.com[/url] ==> [url]http://www.google.com[/url]
NO MATCHING [url="http://www.google.com"]http://www.google.com[/url] ==> [url="http://www.google.com"]http://www.google.com[/url]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the **discard technique** by adding discard patterns at the beginning of your regex like this. So you can add a discard pattern to get rid of tags like this:

```
\[.+?\].*?\[\/.+?\]|(\b(?:https?|ftp|file):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])
discard this --^
which is [...]...[/...]
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/jX0hD9/3)**

As you can see in the screenshot below, you will have your matches in red/green (your original regex) and in blue the discarded patterns.

[image]

Just to let you know, the discard pattern consists of adding all the patterns you want to get rid off separated by OR at the right side of the regex and use a capturing group at the rightest side like this:

```
discard patt1 | discard patt2 | discard pattN | (capture this content)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Comment: Thanks.  So right now on my prelim testing (this is in JS) its literally discarding/deleting the patterns that already have [url] in them.  So the output of [url]http://www.google.com[/url] becomes [url][/url].   I would rather just ignore the ones that have [url] already in them

Comment: @Mark to leverage this regex trick in javascript you will have to add some code with logic. For instance, if capturing group is empty, don't do anything, else the capturing group contains data then do the logic you want

Comment: You are correct, that would be a great way of doing it, but was hoping to accomplish this all via regex if possible

Comment: @Mark unfortunately not, you can't achieve this with javascript. This regex trick works perfectly well with PCRE, but for javascript you need additional code.

Answer (score 0):

i would use this regex and replace with `bbcode` only if 1st group is empty (meaning no `bbcode` has been already placed)

```
/(\[url\])?(\b(https?|ftp|file):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])(\[\/url\])?/gi
```